# SQL Update not updating fields in Access Database

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple days, and have not been able to find out what is wrong with the following code.  When I click a button to update, nothing gets updated. By the way, I am using an html table to display a customer's information, and then using those textboxes in the table to update the fields. But the SQL Update Statement just isn't working. Here is the code:

```
Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection 

    Dim myCommand As OleDbCommand  

    Dim ID As Integer 

    Dim mySQLString As String, strFirstName As String, strLastName As String, strPhone As String, strEmail, strComment As String, Employee As String, DateCalled, TimeCalled, DateEdited As datetime 

    myConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\wfccdb\datagridview\app_data\t3corp.mdb;")  

    myConnection.Open()  

    ID = Request.QueryString.Item("r") 

    Employee = tbEMP.Text  

    strFirstName = tbFname.Text

    strLastName = tbLname.Text

    strPhone = tbPhone.Text 

    strEmail = tbEmail.Text 

    DateCalled = Convert.ToDateTime(tbDateCalled.Text)  
    TimeCalled = Convert.ToDateTime(tbTimeCalled.Text)  
    strComment = tbComment.Text  
    DateEdited = Now

    mySQLString = "UPDATE customers SET Employee='" + Employee + "', FirstName='" + strFirstName + "', LastName='" + strLastName + "', Phone='" + strPhone + "', Email='" + strEmail + "', DateCalled='" + DateCalled + "', " + _
    "TimeCalled='" + TimeCalled + "', Comment='" + strComment + "', DateEdited='" + DateEdited + "' WHERE ReferenceID=" & Val(ID) & "" 

    myCommand = New OleDbCommand  

    myCommand.Connection = myConnection

    myCommand.CommandText = mySQLString

    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection.Close()



    Response.Redirect("ViewEditRecords.aspx?r=" + Request.QueryString.Item("r"))


End Sub
```

Comment: Does the generated SQL work correctly if you execute it directly in Access?

Comment: Have tried using the parameters.AddwithValue() ? It is much safer way in vb.net and might do the trick for you...

Comment: @DeanOC I'm not sure how I'd run this query in Access because it is based off of textbox values.

Comment: @wcraft Yes, I actually have used the AddWithValue() parameters to no avail, I was trying this way to make sure I wasn't messing them parametrized queries up, but still no luck

Comment: Also it is a good practice to use try and catch block. Easy to spot the errors.

Comment: @EricHickman Just get the value stored in mySQLString by putting breakpoint and run that query against DB or use try and catch you will catch the error easily .

Comment: Ok, let me try the try catch block right now

Comment: try catch is giving an error saying that there is a syntax error (missing operator) at the employee location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your update SQL string contains a few problems. Let's start from the beginning.

```
mySQLString = "UPDATE customers SET Employee='" + Employee + "', FirstName='" + strFirstName + "', LastName='" + strLastName + "', Phone='" + strPhone + "', Email='" + strEmail + "', DateCalled='" + DateCalled + "', " + _
"TimeCalled='" + TimeCalled + "', Comment='" + strComment + "', DateEdited='" + DateEdited + "' WHERE ReferenceID=" & Val(ID) & ""
```

First of all, notice the three date/time values you are trying to assign DateCalled, TimeCalled, DateEdited. I assume that they are real date values in your Access table. In this case you need to construct the update statement for the column as follows:

```
".... DateCalled=#" + tbDateCalled.Text + "# ...."
```

(you need to surround the date value with #). Do this for TimeCalled as well.

Now, have a look at your `"' WHERE ReferenceID=" & Val(ID) & ""`. If you check what [VAL](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/val.php) function does, it is doing an opposite: converting string to number. So, in your case, you need to use (drop `& ""` as well, as there is no need for it):

```
"' WHERE ReferenceID=" & CStr(ID)
```

And finally, why don't you check the error string after you call `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. I am pretty sure Access would tell you what the errors are

So, to incorporate the suggestions from sgeddes, your final SQL string should look like this:

```
Employee = Replace(Employee, "''", "'")
Employee = Replace(Employee, "'", "''")
Do this for first name, last name, phone, comment and email to minimise the threat of SQL injections

mySQLString = "UPDATE customers SET Employee='" & Employee & "', FirstName='" & strFirstName & "', LastName='" & strLastName & "', Phone='" & strPhone & "', Email='" & strEmail & "', DateCalled=#" & tbDateCalled.Text & "#, " + _
"TimeCalled=#" & tbTimeCalled.Text & "#, Comment='" & strComment & "', DateEdited=Now() WHERE ReferenceID=" & CStr(ID)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I wasn't having any errors.  It just wasn't updating.  I'm also using asp.net, btw.  I have changed the date and time fields and the Val(ID) field to match what you have suggested. However, now I am getting an error when trying to update: 

"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Employee'.  It is passing the actual employee name in the error.

Comment: mySQLString = "UPDATE customers SET Employee=" + Employee + ", FirstName=" + strFirstName + ", LastName=" + strLastName + ", Phone=" + strPhone + ", Email=" + strEmail + ", DateCalled=#" + DateCalled + "#, " + _
            "TimeCalled=#" + TimeCalled + "#, Comment='" + strComment + "', DateEdited=#" + DateEdited + "# WHERE ReferenceID=" & CStr(ID)

Comment: why did you drop single apostrophes around the string values? They were right. All you had to do is just replace single apostrophes with '' (two single apostrophes) inside the string values, as sgeddes suggested. So, return this:  ".... Employee='" + Employee + "', ..."

Comment: something like this: Replace(Employee, "'", "''")

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have misunderstood him, will you show me what you mean?

Comment: for the sake of time, I am skipping the Replace statement because this is an internal site and once I get this working, I will implement parameterized queries.  The rest of my SQLstring looks just like yours.  I am where I started, unfortunately. I am receiving no errors, and the only field getting updated the is DateEdited field.

Comment: what do you mean? only dateEdited updated? Have you tried to copy and paste this query (it is different from yours in many places): mySQLString = "UPDATE customers SET Employee='" & Employee & "', FirstName='" & strFirstName & "', LastName='" & strLastName & "', Phone='" & strPhone & "', Email='" & strEmail & "', DateCalled=#" & tbDateCalled.Text & "#, " + _
"TimeCalled=#" & tbTimeCalled.Text & "#, Comment='" & strComment & "', DateEdited=Now() WHERE ReferenceID=" & CStr(ID)

Comment: I have copied and pasted your string, and I'm getting the same thing.  Fields are not being updated based off of the string variables and the textboxes. The only field that is successfully getting updated is the DateEdited field.

Comment: are you sure your string values contain the updated values. You can do Response.WRite(mySQLString) before you call the database update to see what is being written. I do not believe it is possible to have just a single column updated from the SQL command

Comment: Thanks for your help once again, I know this is frustrating, trust me, I've been dealing with it for a few days :).  I ran the response.write(mysqlstring) and pasted that string into access and it ran fine.

Comment: So something seems to be messing up when it comes to executing the update command based on those values other than the DateEdited

Comment: is by any chance the database you are looking at not at this location: Data Source=\wfccdb\datagridview\app_data\t3corp.mdb. Can you try setting an absolute path?

Comment: Would the DateEdited field be able to be updated if the database wasn't able to be accessed? Could it have anything to do with my html table? I have records in the database, and a gridview that populates the records. Users can then click a link in the gridview to open a specific record and see the details. That is where I am using a table to populate an individual record's details. I am using the textboxes in my table for updates if a user needs to change some detail in a record. They then can click update and there is where we are having this issue

Comment: is it possible that your code "reads" old data from the html table. All I can see in your original post is a ButtonClicked event handler that makes me think that this is a test GUI application. Why don't you do Response.WRite(mySQLString), so that you see on the html page you are using the actual SQL statement that is about to be executed. In this case you will see what is about to be updated

Comment: I don't think so because the SQL statement is mapped to what's in the textboxes at the time of the page being displayed. And then it will take whatever information is in those textboxes when the button is clicked and SHOULD update the database with that info. I mean correct me if I am wrong, but that sounds correct to me :/

Comment: I feel like you actually are right with the code reading old table data.  The SQL string isn't pulling any updated data from the textboxes, it's pulling what is already in the record. Any idea on what to do with that? How come it's pulling old data and not reading what's in the actual textboxes?

Comment: Ask another question and tag it as ASP.Net. I have not used .Net for a few years and may have an outdated knowledge. I am pretty sure there are many experts here who are able to help you

Comment: in the meantime I would appreciate if you upvote helpful answers

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to upvote answers as I do not have a high enough reputation to do so.  Also, I figured out what was going on with my update statement.  The statement was correct, but the problem was that I had my textboxes being pre-loaded with data from my database in the Page_Load Event.  Therefore, even though I was clicking a button, it was doing the page_load event first and completely discarding any information being typed in the textboxes to be updated.  So, to remedy this, I posted the code to pre-load my textboxes in the Page_PreRender Event instead and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

First, you really should use parameterized queries -- this is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

With that said, I think at minimum you're having an issue around your DateTime fields -- the proper way to insert MS Access DateTime fields should be with #Date# -- your query is inserting those as strings which won't work in Access.

Also, if any of your fields have apostrophes in them, this will also break -- another reason to use parameterized queries.

Hope this helps a little.

Good luck.

Comment: I am using parameterized queries :) I was just using this as a test to see where my problem is.  I am having the same problem both with and without using parameterized queries.  Ok, so for my Date and Time fields I should do something like this?

    "DateCalled=" + #DateCalled# + ",

Comment: No, you should be doing something like datecalled=#" + datecalled + "#... Basically replace your apostrophe with the #.  Good luck.

Comment: Also, if you are using parameterized queries, you need to specify the data type - by default access infers those to be strings...

Comment: Btw, don't think you can use & when creating your sqlstring in your where criteria - surprised that doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: hmm, yeah I'm not sure, I changed it to a "+" and still receiving the same error.

Comment: I would Response.Write your mySQLString and then Response.End and see if you can't get it to work in Access -- much easier to debug there.  Any chance and of the variables have apostrophes?  Feel free to post the SQL String.

Comment: Here is my up-to-date SQLstring:          mySQLString = "UPDATE customers SET Employee='" + Employee + "', FirstName='" + strFirstName + "', LastName='" + strLastName + "', Phone='" + strPhone + "', Email='" + strEmail + "', DateCalled=#" + DateCalled + "#, " + _
            "TimeCalled=#" + TimeCalled + "#, Comment='" + strComment + "', DateEdited=#" + DateEdited + "# WHERE ReferenceID=" + CStr(ID)

Comment: Sorry -- please post the actual value of the string -- Response.WRite(mySQLString) -- that we we can determine if something is wrong with any of your parameters.

Comment: Well if you're using .Net (and not Classic ASP), just put a breakpoint on that line, and then step into the code.  You should be able to get the string that way.

Comment: Here is my sql string:  UPDATE customers SET Employee='Eric Hickman', FirstName='testFname', LastName='testLname', Phone='testPhone', Email='testEmail', DateCalled=#1/24/2013 8:19:52 PM#, TimeCalled=#1/24/2013 8:19:52 PM#, Comment='testComment', DateEdited=Now() WHERE ReferenceID=997

Comment: That looks pretty good to me -- take it and run it in MS Access -- if it works, then you're error is elsewhere.  Are your DateCalled, TimeCalled and DateEdited fields DateTimes in Access?  Don't see anything else wrong with it -- is your Phone numeric by chance.  Running out of ideas...  Good luck.

Comment: I really appreciate your helping me. Yes, the datecalled, timecalled, and dateedited fields are DateTimes in Access. The Phone is just a text field. I just ran the query in Access, and it ran fine.

Comment: So, it's not a problem with the SQL string itself, it seems to not be pulling new data from the textboxes, it seems to be pulling old data instead.